# How to qsub an R script as a heredoc?

Tags: python, r, bash, heredoc, qsub

I can submit a bash heredoc directly to `qsub` like this:

```
my_var="foobar"
qsub <<HERE
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "$my_var"
HERE
```

And I can run an R script with a bash heredoc like this:

```
my_var="foobar"
Rscript - "arg1" "arg2" <<E0F
  ## R code
  cat("\nR loaded\n")
  args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
  cat("Script args are:\n")
  args
  print("$my_var")
  sessionInfo()
E0F
```

And I can submit a saved R script directly to `qsub` without a bash wrapper script, like this:

```
qsub -wd $PWD -o :${PWD}/ -j y -b y Rscript my_script.R "arg_1" "arg_2"
```

where `my_script.R` looks like this:

```
$ cat my_script.R
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
cat("\nR loaded\n")
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
cat("Script args are:\n")
args
sessionInfo()
```

However, if I try to combine this and submit the R script directly as a heredoc....

```
my_var="foobar"
qsub -wd $PWD -o :${PWD}/ -j y -b y Rscript - "foo" "bar" <<E0F
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
cat("\nR loaded\n")
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
cat("Script args are:\n")
args
print("$my_var")
sessionInfo()
E0F
```

... it does not work. I get nothing output. No error messages either.

Is there a way to do this? Also interested in the same for Python. I was considering trying nested heredocs, but the need for literal `\t` indentation is not going to work well since my IDE's all replace them automatically with spaces.

Also this is using Sun Grid Engine `qsub`

Comment: Why? Just write proper `#!` scripts for either `/usr/bin/Rscript` or, my favourite, `/usr/bin/r` from [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) (and on CRAN [here](https://cran.r-project.org/package=littler)).  That last one also does `stdin` so you could try to shoehorn your heredocs into it.

Comment: Reproducibility & documentation. I want my R and Python code embedded within the surrounding bash script & Markdown notebook. When I have multiple script files to keep track of things get confusing and messy easily.

Comment: "Wishing alone does not make it so."  Look at the source of `/usr/bin/R`, it is itself a shell script.  Hence my hints at alternatives...

Comment: Doesn't work. I think the issue is with how `qsub` handles stdin when in binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was wrong about the indentation requirements, and nested heredocs actually do work for this.

```
# find files I need to process
files_I_want="$(find /my/dir/ -type f -name "*.txt")"
output_dir="/other/dir"

# iterate over files
for some_file in $files_I_want; do
    # set output file path
    output_file="${output_dir}/$(basename "$some_file")"

    # submit bash heredoc qsub job
    qsub -wd $PWD <<E0F
# R example
# start R heredoc
Rscript - "${some_file}" "${output_file}" <<E0F2
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

my_crazy_function <- function(input_file, output_file){
    print("input file is:")
    print(input_file)
    print("output file is:")
    print(output_file)
}
print("This is R")
my_crazy_function(input_file = args[1], output_file = args[2])

E0F2

# Python example
python - "${some_file}" "${output_file}" <<E0F3
import sys

def my_crazy_function(input_file, output_file):
    print "Input file is: ", input_file
    print "Output file is: ", output_file

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]
print "This is Python"
my_crazy_function(input_file, output_file)
E0F3
E0F

done
```